# System xml source_model name convention

Tags: widgets, system.xml, widget

In system and widget xml file of custom module I use source_model tag. First I used this:

```
<source_model>modulename/system_requesttype</source_model>
```

but then there was conflict with another extension because modulename was the same. After that I changed it to this:

```
<source_model>Company_Modulename_Model_System_Requesttype</source_model>
```

I am wondering if there is any downside of using the second one or if there can be be any problems with Magento compilation?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at 
[Same module name with different namespace conflicting in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711524/same-module-name-with-different-namespace-conflicting-in-magento)

I would strongly suggest renaming your module. By default when magento merge all the config files it will only use the last module config (in alphabetical order or using the depend option order). So anything within your module that uses the model e.g Mage::getModel('modulename/xyz') should not work (since your module seem to be the first one loaded during the merge).

Comment: I need to keep the same name because of old customers who upgrade extension with new version. There is no problem with model because you can add company to model (e.g. Mage::getModel('companyname_modulename/xyz')) if you define such in config file. So my only question is now about if there is any potential problem when using the mentioned name convention for source_model tag inside system xml.